# Consequences of general equation of hydrostatics $\nabla p= -\rho \nabla E$ in terms of surfaces where $p$ and $E$ are constant

Tags: pressure, density, fluid-statics

I'm facing difficulties in understanding the consequences of the general equation of Hydrostatics in the case of conservative forces.

$$\nabla p= -\rho \nabla E\tag{1}$$

Where $p$ is the pressure, $\rho$ is the density and $E$ is the potential energy per unit mass.

The meaning of $(1)$ is clear but not the consequences regarding the surfaces where $p$ is constant and where $E$ is constant.

---

In particular which one of the following two is correct?

$(a)$ The surfaces where $p=constant$ are also surfaces where $E=constant$ and  $\rho=constant$ **indipendently from the fact that $\rho$ is constant for all the liquid or not**.

$(b)$ The surfaces where $p=constant$ are also surfaces where $E=constant$ and  $\rho=constant$ **only if all the fluid has constant $\rho$**.

---

On the one side $(a)$ seems right because, the two gradients are parallel indipendently from $\rho$ (which is a scalar) and that means they are perpendicular to the same surfaces where the two corresponding quantities are constant $\implies$ the surfaces are the same.

On the other side take the example of two not mixable fluids in a U manometer.
[image]

The book says "the pressure is the same on the horizonal surface passing through 3 and 4". That's ok but if $(a)$ was correct than $p$ should be the same also on the surfaces passing through 2 and 5. In fact I can consider the fluid made of  the red one plus a part of the blue one (the one between 3 and 2), $\rho$ is not constant but it is still a fluid. But that is not correct.

---

So which one between $(a)$ and $(b)$ is correct and what are the **mathematical and physical reasons**?

I would say that $(b)$ is correct but, beside my example, I could not find any mathematical reason why $(a)$ should be wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

(b) is correct.  Your equation applies only if all the fluid is the same fluid.

Suppose that, as in your problem, E = gz, where z is the elevation above the base.  So, the component of your equation in the z direction becomes $$\frac{dp}{dz}=-\rho g$$  Because points 3 and 4 involve the same fluid, the pressure at these two points is the same, say $p_{3-4}$.  Now, if $\Delta z$ represents the difference in elevation between points 2 and 3, and also between points 4 and 5, the pressures at points 2 and 5 are as follows:
$$p_2=p_{3-4}-\rho_B \Delta z$$
$$p_5=p_{3-4}-\rho_R \Delta z$$
where $\rho_B$ is the density of the blue fluid and $\rho_R$ is the density of the red fluid.  You can see from this that the pressures at points 2 and 5 are not equal because the two densities are not equal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get the example but why $(a)$ should be wrong just looking at equation $(1)$? The density is a scalar, hence, even if it is not constant, it does not change the direction of $\nabla E$, which is still perpendicular to the surfaces where $E=cost$ and from $(1)$ these surfaces should also be with $p=cost$, because $\nabla p \| \nabla E$, indipendently from the value of $\rho$.

Comment: Well, the example I gave clearly shows that this is not the case.  The gradient of p changes when the density changes even though the gradient of E doesn't change.  You have got to get your head around the mathematics.  It's not really a question of physics.  If the rho were inside the del on the right hand side so that it was $\nabla (\rho E)$, then (a) would be correct.  But, it's not.